# How can I insert lines before a specific line?

Tags: python, bash

Suppose the following file:

```
...

OW             8  16.000000  0.00000000  A     0.31507524       0.635968
HW             1   1.008000  0.00000000  A              0              0


[ moleculetype ]
; Name            nrexcl
system1          3

[ atoms ]
;   nr       type  resnr residue  atom   cgnr    charge       mass  typeB    chargeB      massB

...
```

I want to insert the lines

```
#ifdef POSRES
#include "posres.itp"
#endif
```

to the file like:

```
...

OW             8  16.000000  0.00000000  A     0.31507524       0.635968
HW             1   1.008000  0.00000000  A              0              0

#ifdef POSRES
#include "posres.itp"
#endif

[ moleculetype ]
; Name            nrexcl
system1          3

[ atoms ]
;   nr       type  resnr residue  atom   cgnr    charge       mass  typeB    chargeB      massB

...
```

I always want to insert the lines before `[ moleculetype ]`.

Could you tell me how to realise it by python or bash?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I do this is that I make my own print function that will print it and add it to a list, as such:

```py
sent = []
def log(message):
    sent.append(message)
    print(message)
```

Next, add a function to insert a message:

```py
def add_message(index, message):
    sent.insert(index, message)
    clear_screen()
    resend()
```

Also add functions to clear the screen and resend all the messages. 50 lines or more in the shell will be squeezed, meaning 49 lines will be used.

```py
def clear_screen():
    print("\n"*49)

def resend():
    for message in sent:
        print(message)
```

For an example of it working, add the following code to the bottom of the file.

```py
import time
clear_screen()
log("A")
time.sleep(1)
log("B")
time.sleep(1)
add_message(1, "C")
```

Comment: You can also add functions to remove messages following this code as an example